# What is the difference between a transition function and a transition kernel?

Tags: markov-process, transition-matrix

Context of Question:

"Algorithms for Reinforcement Learning", Csaba Szepesvari pg 11

Excerpt:

In the case of the inventory control problem, the MDP was conveniently specied by a transition function f (cf., (4)). In fact, **transition functions are as powerful as transition kernels**: any MDP gives rise to some transition function f and any transition function f gives rise to some MDP.